# kendoui agular2 grid Select row by default

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

Is it possible to select row by default in Kendu-ui-angular2 grid?

I need to select first row in every grid page by default.

(on init and on page change event)

thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Currently setting default selection for the Kendo UI Grid is not supported. It is part of the plans, so please stay tuned.

Comment: Thank you for the information,
where can I follow it?